# sqlalchemy multiple statements with multiple parameters to pass

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, parameter-passing, multiple-select-query

I've created a valid connection through sqlalchemy when I didn't pass variables into my tape_query string, which is a multi-statement query. However, when I tried to pass sp_input through :sp into the string per below, I get a KeyError: 'data_date' error per below. What am I missing?

what works:

```
"""
USE DATABASE this;
USE SCHEMA that;
SELECT * from table where id=100;
"""

conn = engine.connect()
for q in tape_query.split(";"):
    conn.execute(q)
```

what doesn't work:

```
tape_query=
"""
USE DATABASE this;
USE SCHEMA that;
SELECT * from table where id=:sp;
"""

sp_input=200

conn = engine.connect()
for q in tape_query.split(";"):
    conn.execute(q, {"sp":sp_input})
```

the error looks like this:

> ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py in execute(self, command, params, timeout, >_exec_async, _do_reset, _put_callback, _put_azure_callback, _put_callback_output_stream, _get_callback, >_get_azure_callback, _get_callback_output_stream, _show_progress_bar, _statement_params, _is_internal, >_no_results, _use_ijson, _is_put_get, _raise_put_get_error, _force_put_overwrite)
> 509                                  params, processed_params)
> 510                 if len(processed_params) > 0:
> --> 511                     query = command % processed_params
> 512                 else:
> 513                     query = command
>
> KeyError: 'data_date'

Comment: Wrap `q` with `text()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try something like this? If not, then maybe dig into the documentation.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine('postgresql://scott:tiger@localhost:5432/mydatabase')

sp_input = [100, 200]
query_string = f"select * from table1 where id={sp_input[0]}; select * from table2 where id={sp_input[1]}"

connection = engine.raw_connection()
try:
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query_string)
    results_one = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.nextset()
    results_two = cursor.fetchall()
    cursor.close()
finally:
    connection.close()
```